Get YouTube shorts analytics from YouTube analytics api
I am trying to write a script for my channel shorts analytics  containing specific data .There doesn't seem to be any API calls within youtube  api that will return certain important metrics like "viewed vs swiped", "shown in feed", etc.
What I'm trying to do is find a way to analyze the corelation between engagement/views/swipe rate and the shown in feed metric.
I read YouTube analytics API but and other third parties API but didn't got solution .Is there any way to scrape it with python?

YouTube analytics api predates shorts you are not going to see this information

Do you have these metrics for regular videos? If so, then this Stack Overflow answer should meet your needs.

No these metrics are not for regular videos.
